# Convergence rate of finite element method?

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-element-method, elliptic-operators, galerkin-methods

Suppose I have a convex polygon $\Omega$ with $n$ sides and I want to find eigenvalues of the Laplacian with mixed Robin boundary conditions:
$$
-\Delta u=k^2u\text{ in }\Omega
$$
$$
a_iu+b_i\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0\text{ on }\Gamma_i
$$

where $a_i,b_i$ are constant and $\partial\Omega=\cup_{i=1}^n\Gamma_i$. If I try and solve this via finite elements of equal smoothness and accuracy $p$, is it true that I gain order $2p$ for convergence to the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions?